# Monitor data connection based on location constantly

Tags: data-connection, location-services, resource-monitoring

I was wondering if there was way to ping `google.com` (or any other stable site) and record my GPS location. It would then append the result of the ping, GPS position, and the time to a log file on my phone. It would run every 10 seconds or so.

Basically, I just want to get a view of my phone's Internet connection throughout the day and at different times. After a full day running, I could then look at the generated log and figure out all sorts of interesting analytics for my phone.

Is it possible, perhaps using apps, script, or anything?

Comment: It looks like a customized app. You need to make an app yourself, or have someone make it for you.

Comment: I think this question could be on topic if you would rephrase it like "How can I keep track of my phones data connectivity and location (GPS)?" See also the sites FAQ and http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/1181/how-to-ask-android-questions-the-smart-way

Comment: I have tweaked the question to make it more about a problem to be solved than an app to be found. I think it can be re-opened.

Comment: @StephenCagle: GPS can be pretty battery-intensive. Are you sure you'd want something like this firing every 10 seconds? Further, it takes a long time for a GPS fix; the GPS receiver would need to be on constantly.

Answer (score 1):

There are no apps appear to suit to your need. But you could use two separate apps to do what you need to do.

Use Googles [My Tracks](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.maps.mytracks&hl=en) to record your location data automatically. This app,

- Record data of where you are using GPS coordinates.
- Allows you to monitor your trip or the places of visits in 3D maps.
- Promotes easy sharing of your data.

Use [Traffic Counter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.carl.trafficcounter&hl=en) to monitor your data usage. This app,

- Records your data usage details real time
- Offer some good in-app analysis tools
- Can be used to monitor calls, SMSs, WiFi, apps, etc. as well

With the help of these two, you can achieve your objective. No need to ping a site!